# Can an Activity register for both Sticky and non-Sticky Events in EventBus Android

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

In my activity, I want to register it for both [Sticky and Noo-Sticky Events]. Because I am posting both type of events from Service which should be fired in My Activity ...

Typically, I want to achieve this ...

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
EventBus.getDefault().registerSticky(this);
```

And then wanted to perform Actions in

```
public void onEvent(EventSticky1 event){
     // code here ...
}
public void onEvent(EventNonSticky1 event){
         // code here ...
}
```

But, this gives me error like shown below ...

```
de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: Subscriber class MainActivity already registered to event class EventSticky1
                                                     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.subscribe(EventBus.java:179)
                                                     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:165)
                                                     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.registerSticky(EventBus.java:151)
```

How can achieve this ???

Thanks In Advance.